# DAL->Design :: simple vs. oop model && property vs. method

Tags: oop, model, data-access-layer

Suppose you want to implement a Data Access Layer that takes care of saving your (java) object to a data store.

A model in your store, represents an entity (table in sql), an entity has members that either contain information about the entity itself, or a relation to a parent entity (e.g. parentId).

Now there are these cases:

1. the model has members with simple data types (int, char, String). This is the most used case? You members are strongly typed and securely accessed throughout the app, but you need a dal for each entity.
2. same as above, but for simplicity and extendability, you chose to implement your model as map. This is similar to the datastore API of AppEngine. Your members are accessed by name in your app, but you have a single generic dal and all entities are easily extendable.
3. the model has other models as members, we call it the full model. this time, you can get all relational entities inside your model. The DAL is less flexible, and you may increase or decrease consistency problems, but now you can use OOP to its fullest at the model level.

I hope I didn't miss something above. 
Based on your experience, what do you think is best environment for best approach? think not huge enterprise app, but rather standard project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading up on the [aggregates](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/16/ddd-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx) pattern as part of DDD (domain driven design). The basic idea is to split your full entity model into logical groups and then to provide [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for each aggregate root (the main entity of the group) which saves all entities that form the aggregate. This provides full use of OOP whilst not infringing consistency issues. In general I have found this to be the most 'organised' approach.

Comment: it seems we can use aggregates to do this:
 - define an abstract car model
 - define a 4x4 and a sedan model, inheriting the car members
 - use aggregates to store the two